# in gradle build.gradle file - how can i check if a project exists?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Let's say in a build.gradle file I want to do something like:

`ext.sharepointBuildDir = project(":MainProject:sharepoint").buildDir.path`

But in certain configurations that project may not exist.

How can I check "does a gradle project exist"?

Comment: Not sure whether there's a built-in mechanism.  But assuming you're using a conventional directory structure, could you just look for the relevant directory before executing the above line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a `findProject` method, which is according to it's [description](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#findProject%28java.lang.String%29)

> Locates a project by path. If the path is relative, it is interpreted relative to this project.
>
> Returns: The project with the given path. Returns null if no such project exists.

So, you can simply use it as follows:

```
if (findProject(':MainProject:sharepoint') != null) {
    println 'project exists'
} else {
    println 'project does not exist'
}
```